# Binding empty dictionary to a listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

When i try to bind a dictionary to a listbox I get an ArgumentException. Cannot bind to the new value member.

I use the following code. 
Can any one tell me what is wrong. Because when i enter i row in the dictionary its working fine...

```
this.contactpersonenListBox = new Dictionary<int, string>();

lsContactpersonen.DataSource = new BindingSource(this.contactpersonenListBox, null);
lsContactpersonen.DisplayMember = "Value";
lsContactpersonen.ValueMember = "Key";
```

Comment: why do you want to bind an empty dictionary to a list box?

Comment: In my case, the dictionary was populated dynamically based on the results of a query. Sometimes a query may turn up nothing. Leaving the datasource to be an empty dictionary. The resulting listbox would show a single entry called "(Collection)."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't make a ton of sense to bind an empty dictionary since the dictionary object doesn't report any changes, so adding an item to the dictionary after setting the data source won't show up in the ListBox.

But to get rid of the error, try setting it like this:

```
BindingSource b = new BindingSource();
b.DataSource = this.contactpersonenListBox;
lsContactpersonen.DisplayMember = "Value";
lsContactpersonen.ValueMember = "Key";
lsContactpersonen.DataSource = b;
```

Comment: this is great , but now my listbox sets an item with the text (collection) Is there a way to get rid of that

Comment: @WillemT I'm not seeing what you are seeing.  My ListBox is empty.

Comment: When i bind the dictionary when its empty i have an item called (collection) in my listbox. as soon as i populate the dictionary the item dissappears

Comment: @WillemT I can't repro with the code I have.  Maybe update your post with the code you are using if it's different.

Comment: I use the code that you posted above. and i use a normal listbox. I created a function that executes the code at form load

Comment: Thank anyway the main question is answered :p